# Set some column in DB2 table as updatable false, is it possible?

Tags: sql, db2, constraints

I need to make some values in my DB2 table unchangable, i.e. I can insert or delete, but can't change. Is it possible to do? I know that hibernate has annotaion updatable false, but does DB2 has something at the level of DB2 itself?

Comment: ...probably not.  You could add an "instead of update" trigger, I suppose.  What is it you're trying to keep from updating?  What is it you're trying to protect against?  In most cases being able to insert/delete related rows is just as bad, if not worse.  Also, would make fixing any errors very difficult.

Comment: Calendar with events, I have foreign key in EVENTS table to CALENDARS table, id of the calendar. Upon update I'd like that everything would be changeable except this ID to avoid abuse and possible cracking. Actually I can do this by using different query on INSERT/UPDATE, right now I use MERGE. But I'm lazy and if it could be done by defining this constraint it'd be much easier to me.

Comment: ...What does an id-related row in the calendar table represent?  A specific day?  So does that mean I can't correct what day something is on if I mess up?   And your threat model is messed up - if I can (maliciously) update a row, usually I can delete/insert them too; I can make my modifications that way instead, so this alone wouldn't prevent abuse/cracking.  Depending on your application design I might be able to update an existing row that has my desired calendar id, which would be worse.  You need to rethink your "defense".

Comment: This ID defines to which calendar this event related. Actually you're right, If I want to make my app more safe I need to implement more complex solution and to prevent delete/insert rows from unauthorized users too. Thank you for your opinion.